# Mysql Populating Pivot Table

Tags: mysql

I've created the following to quickly populate a pivot table:

```
INSERT INTO `document_product` (`product_id`, `document_id`)
SELECT `olddocs.product_id`, `documents.id`
FROM `olddocs`
JOIN `documents`
ON `olddocs.location` = `documents.location`
```

I get the error: **Unknown column 'olddocs.product_id' in 'field list'** but all the fields are correct, so is my ordering/grouping wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your backticks are misplaced. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `document_product` (`product_id`, `document_id`)
SELECT `olddocs`.`product_id`, `documents`.`id`
FROM `olddocs`
JOIN `documents`
ON `olddocs`.`location` = `documents`.`location`
```